# At what point are query expressions invoked?

Tags: lasso-lang

In the below example would the queryable `#q` be evaluated a second time?

```
local(max = 10, m = 5)

local(q = with n in 1 to 10 select #n+#m) 

#q // 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15

if(true) => {
   #q // is it invoke here like the above?
}
```

I suspect not, but if that's the case is it #q->asString that invokes the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're right. Here's a simple test calling a counter thread object that increments on each call.

```
define test_count => thread {
    data private val = 0
    public asstring => {
      .val += 1
      return .val
    }
}

local(max = 10, m = 5)
test_count

local(q = with n in 1 to 10 select #n+#m + integer(test_count -> asstring))
'<br />'
test_count
'<br />'
#q
'<br />'
test_count
'<br />'
if(true) => {
   #q
}
'<br />'
test_count
```

Result ->

1
2
9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27
13
14

The second call for #q is never processed. You can however force it to run by outputting it.